# Should I center the data when performing Laplacian Eigenmap or any other manifold learning?

Tags: time-series, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional, centering, manifold-learning

Suppose I have a high dimensional non-stationary non-linear time series,

then is it advisable to center the data on the mean when performing laplacian eigenmap?

I've heard somewhere that when performing machine learning, the performance and accuracy increases if the data is centered on the mean.

If it makes any difference, what could be the potential reason?

Answer (score 2):

There are several manifold learning algorithms for which it doesn't make a difference.

**Laplacian Eigenmaps** and **Isomap** only depend on the distances between the points, and translating these points doesn't change that, so it shouldn't make any difference.

**Locally Linear Embedding** also shouldn't depend on that, as it tries to approximate points using linear combinations of other points, and that should be invariant to translations.

Of course there are issues that can stem from numerical errors, but they'll probably mostly depend on the method of obtaining distance matrix.